# Missing jboss.jdbc-driver.org_postgresql_Driver

Tags: jboss7.x

I'm trying to configure a Postgres datasource in standalone.xml. I've put the driver jar in the right place "jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\modules\org\postgresql\main" and this is my "standalone.xml":

```
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine" pool-name="ProcessEngine" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/camunda_process_engine</connection-url>
                <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>postgresql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                    <password>postgres</password>
                </security>                   
            </datasource>
        <drivers>
            </driver>
            <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
```

...

"jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\modules\org\postgresql\main\module.xml"

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
> <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.postgresql">  
>   <resources>  
>   <resource-root path="postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar"/>  
>   </resources>  
>   <dependencies>  
>       <module name="javax.api"/>  
>       <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
>   </dependencies>  
> </module>
> ```

I'm trying to start server but it shows errors.

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.org_postgresql_Driver (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine, service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine]
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have to add a dependency on your new module to your application.  The easiest way to do this is to add a jboss-deployment-structure.xml to the META-INF of your Ear, or if you just have a war, put it in WEB-INF.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.postgresql" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

When you redeploy, JBoss will know to put your new custom module in the classpath.  Decent guide to classloading in AS7 [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7).